# User determined array dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, minesweeper

I need to write a program Minesweeper.java that takes 3 command-line arguments M, N, and p and produces an M-by-N boolean array where each entry is occupied with probability p. Where I'm stuck is how to create a two dimensional array where the user inputs what the dimensions are. Any help with that part would be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go the main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);

        int myArray[][] = new int[a][b];

        //your code
    }
```

It's java. Chapter 0